# Logstash Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm trying to setup a ELK stack in docker environment, but I have no luck so far with Logstash. I've got Kibana + Elastic running and connection with one another, but can't get logstash to work. I've tried different configurations and github repos to start with, but nothing seems to work.

I get the following error:

> [logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}

Another thing I get is:

> [2022-09-12T13:16:18,558][ERROR][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Failed to fetch X-Pack information from Elasticsearch. This is likely due to failure to reach a live Elasticsearch cluster.

My docker-compose is:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    command: npm run dev
    container_name: server
    ports:
      - "${NODE_PORT}:${NODE_PORT}"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      DEBUG: nodejs-docker-express:*
    networks:
      - network-name
  kibana:
    build:
      context: ./docker/kibana/
      args:
        ELASTIC_PORT: ${ELASTIC_PORT}
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - "${KIBANA_PORT}:${KIBANA_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro,Z
    environment:
      KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD}
      ELASTIC_PORT: ${ELASTIC_PORT}
    networks:
      - network-name
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: ./docker/elasticsearch/
      args: 
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./docker/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro,z
      - ./docker/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:z
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "${ELASTIC_PORT}:${ELASTIC_PORT}"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - network-name
  logstash:
    build:
      context: ./docker/logstash/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./docker/logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro,Z
    container_name: logstash
    environment:
      ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
      ELASTIC_PORT: ${ELASTIC_PORT}
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "50000:50000/tcp"
      - "50000:50000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    networks:
      - network-name
networks:
  network-name:
    name: "network-name"
    driver_opts:
      icc: "true"
    driver: bridge
```

logstash.conf

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}
## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
    elasticsearch { 
      hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
      user => "elastic"
      password => "dxAq9YLjR23VqcA4oS1I"
      #ssl => true
      ssl_certificate_verification => false
      timeout => 240
      #cacert => '${LS_HOME}/config/ssl/ca.pem'
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

logstash.yml

```yaml
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
config.reload.automatic: true
log.level: debug

queue.type: persisted
queue.max_bytes: 1gb
queue.checkpoint.writes: 1
```

ENV file

```
#ELK CONFIG
ELASTIC_PORT=9200
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=dxAq9YLjR23VqcA4oS1I
ELASTIC_VERSION=8.4.0
#KIBANA
KIBANA_PORT=5601
KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD=1cDUbBrO8XRosNoayRpy
#BEATS

#LOGSTASH
LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD=C9i0SgSq3loKYbdooKTV
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. I've generated new password for all the users several times, rebuilded containers and nothing seems to work for logstash :(

Comment: Could you provide us the env file please ?

Comment: yes, sure, sorry. I've edited my comment. I've removed all the variables from the logsash and added them manually to be sure that they are passed in correctly and everything works, after that I will replace them with the `.env` variables.

Comment: The .env file is a good practice. It centralize all those info. You are better off using it. Check my response I think I found your issue

Comment: I will try it out, but I don't think the problem is in the environment variable of elastic, since I can log in it successfully with kibana and everything is fine. I will check if there is anything else changed in the config later on tonight, thank you ^^

Comment: Hey there, is it fixed ?

Comment: Sadly no :(. Still looking for the problem or a way to debug it :(

Comment: have you looked at my edit ? the password ?

Comment: Yes, that is not the case sadly :(. I can login in kibana with the elastic user and everything works just fine, not the same case for logstash doe :(

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

The Elasticsearch service is not on the same network.

`elasticsearch` is on `network-name`.
`kibana` and `logstash` are on `tower-defense`

Then in the environment of `elasticsearch` service, you refer to `${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}` for the password of elastic ... isn't it a typo ?

## Solution

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./
      target: dev
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    command: npm run dev
    container_name: server
    ports:
      - "${NODE_PORT}:${NODE_PORT}"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      DEBUG: nodejs-docker-express:*
    networks:
      - network-name
  kibana:
    build:
      context: ./docker/kibana/
      args:
        ELASTIC_PORT: ${ELASTIC_PORT}
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - "${KIBANA_PORT}:${KIBANA_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro,Z
    environment:
      KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD}
      ELASTIC_PORT: ${ELASTIC_PORT}
    networks:
      - tower-defense
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: ./docker/elasticsearch/
      args: 
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./docker/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro,z
      - ./docker/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:z
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "${ELASTIC_PORT}:${ELASTIC_PORT}"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - tower-defense
  logstash:
    build:
      context: ./docker/logstash/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./docker/logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro,Z
    container_name: logstash
    environment:
      ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
      ELASTIC_PORT: ${ELASTIC_PORT}
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "50000:50000/tcp"
      - "50000:50000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    networks:
      - tower-defense
networks:
  tower-defense:
    name: "network-name"
    driver_opts:
      icc: "true"
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I've forgot to replace them, sorry. They are all in the same network.

Comment: I did manage to connect from http://localhost:9200/ with the logstash_internal user that i've created and got a response from the instance but the logstash instance is still not connecting, network seems to be okay, they are all under the same bridge network :(